# Access attribute and method names with slashes or asterisks defined in Hy from Python

Tags: hy

If I were to do the following:

```
(setv a/b 12)
```

How would I access the variable in Python, such as from a regular python module, or simply using `(py)`?

```
(py "print(a/b)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [mangling](https://docs.hylang.org/en/master/language/syntax.html#mangling):

```
=> (setv a/b 12)
=> a/b
12
=> (hy.mangle "a/b")
"hyx_aXsolidusXb"
=> hyx_aXsolidusXb
12
=> (py "print(hyx_aXsolidusXb)")
12
=> (py "print(globals()[hy.mangle('a/b')])")
12
```