# Render mangled hy attribute names as regular strings

Tags: hy

If I have an attribute `self.internal/freezer` in a class, and I raise an error via `(raise (AttributeError f"Sorry! '{attr}' doesn't exist as an attribute!"))`, how can I get the attribute name to render as `internal/freezer` instead of `hyx_internalXsolidusXfreezer`? For example, I already tried `(hy.eval attr)` with the `f-string`, but it still came out mangled.

Comment: Did you read this section, which I linked you to earlier? https://docs.hylang.org/en/master/language/syntax.html#mangling

Comment: I just did; thank you! Er... Which question did you link that in, again...? And I just found the documentation for `unmangle` in the hy core docs.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70690752

Comment: Oh, lord, yes; I'm so sorry, I just read the example! Thank you so much for all the help! Should I just answer my own question, then?

Comment: Sounds like a plan.

Comment: Done! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Kodiologist in the comments linking the [mangling section in hylang's syntax documentation](https://docs.hylang.org/en/master/language/syntax.html#mangling); `unamgling` can be achieved via the aptly named `hy.unmangle` function, documented [here](https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/language/core.html#unmangle) as well.